# Where will the Pioneer, Voyager and New Horizons spacecraft be after one galactic orbit?

Tags: voyager, new-horizons, pioneer

After the Pioneer, Voyager and New Horizons spacecraft complete one orbit of the Milky Way (in approx. 230-250 million years or one "galactic year"), how close will they then be to our solar system?

(Editing my question for clarification) The reason for asking the question is to understand whether these spacecraft that are now in orbit around the center of the galaxy will behave analogously to an object that was thrust away from the ISS and then meets up with the ISS exactly one orbit later. I am assuming that the gravitational pull of the galactic core will prevent the spacecraft from rising above or below the galactic plane for ever and that they will be in a similar orbit to the solar system, just inclined to it. Is that correct?

Answer (score 31):

Oversimplifying by taking the current velocity of each probe and multiplying it by 250 million years, I get:

- [Voyager 1](https://voyager.jpl.nasa.gov/mission/status/) - 10,000 light years away
- [Voyager 2](https://voyager.jpl.nasa.gov/mission/status/) - 9,600 light years away
- [New Horizons](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/missions/new-horizons/in-depth/#:~:text=As%20of%20March%202019%2C%20New,explore%20additional%20Kuiper%20Belt%20objects.) - 9,300 light years away
- [Pioneer 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pioneer_10) - 7,800 light years away
- [Pioneer 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pioneer_11) - 7,000 light years away

Admittedly this ignores slowing down due to the sun's gravity (definitely significant).  It also ignores any gravity effects from any stars it passes along the way (probably significant, but as as @GdD mentions we don't know).

For comparison, Wikipedia puts the diameter of the [Milky way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milky_Way) at 150,000 to 200,000 light years.

Comment: This is pretty good answer actually. "Somewhere in Milky way, and still on the same side of it as earth."

Comment: @jpa unless it gets a gravity assist from a freak black hole that shoots it out of the galaxy at 10% the speed of light. While definitely extremely unlikely, it's possible!

Comment: Wouldn't actually running into something be more likely? And depending on the nature of the impacted object the probe might or might not reasonably be considered to exist afterward. Although in that kind of time frame it would also be possible for whatever the probe impacted to also be flung out of the galaxy.

Comment: @JohnDvorak Wouldn't that require a black hole moving at 5% the speed of light?

Comment: @lirtosiast it would. And yes, I have no clue what could cause a black hole - even a small one - to be launched at that speed. Maybe a close approach to an orbiting pair could give it enough boost?

Comment: Aren't those velocities heliocentric? If they are, it should be noted that in 250 million years the probes are expected to have completed a galactic orbit, although being still near the Sun.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir to quote hitchhiker's guide to the galaxy: "Space is big. You just won't believe how vastly, hugely, mind-bogglingly big it is. I mean, you may think it's a long way down the road to the chemist's, but that's just peanuts to space." (One of the rare occassions Adams was probably underestimating a fact). The chance that you run into something outside of our solar system is almost zero, so you can with almost certainty say none of the spacecraft will hit something large enough in a given timeframe.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir adding to what Paul said, a satellite going through space is roughly analogous to a neutrino going through the Earth.  What looks solid to us is essentially empty space to a neutrino.  Likewise while there are many billions of objects in space, it is so big it looks essentially empty to anything traveling through it.

Comment: I'm aware of all that, however actually running into something still seems like it would be much more likely than getting launched out of the galaxy by a black-hole interaction simply because black holes are a tiny fraction of all the possible objects.

Comment: Perhaps more likely would be aliens discovering them and taking them to their planet :)

Comment: @Barmar it's actually an easter egg in <redacted>. Sadly, you can't actually take it home with you, but it's definitely out of place in the game's solar system.

Answer (score 21):

We don't know as there's no way to calculate it exactly. To do so we'd have to have extremely accurate data on every gravitational interaction these space probes will ever be exposed to. This would require accurate information on the location, mass and vector of every single body in the galaxy, that means every star, every gas cloud, nebula, planet then all the way down to small rocks. Then we would have to perfectly model every gravitational interaction between every single one of these bodies in order to map stellar shift and the movement of objects for the next several hundred million years, and be able to account for the gravitational influence of extremely distant objects. Then we could plot the spacecrafts' paths through this gravitational map.

We don't have nearly enough data to do this. The milky way galaxy has an *estimated* 250 billion stars plus or minus 150 billion. We don't even know how many stars are in the galaxy, much less their exact mass, position or other direction of movement. That's just stars, we can estimate the number of planets from our existing observations, without knowing their positions and mass. Even if we had the data we don't have the computing power to calculate it.

Comment: I commend you for even making an effort to write this answer. I know there are no stupid questions but I don't know what OP was expecting.

Comment: And we could add the problem of dark matter & dark energy, discrepancies in estimates of cosmological constants,...  Hey I know! We'll use TensorFlow!  :-)

Comment: Well, you would hope we will have those solved in 200 million years @CarlWitthoft.

Comment: @GdD  At which point we could observe; we wouldn't need to predict their position :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft ok, first let's measure the universe 500000 times from big bang to heat death, so we have enough data for learning our neural network.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - no experiment and measurement show ANY variation in your "cosmological constants" - what makes you assume those have any influence

Comment: @eagle275    .....yet.

Comment: Do we really need to know about all the stars, verus just the ones in the general vicinity of the Solar System? The rest of the galaxy is far enough away from the spacecraft that they can be aggregated.

Comment: @Barmar that's what I thought too, but looking at [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/44526/12102) we see that in 250 million years they go pretty far; roughly 10,000 light years! We probably do know *something* about *most* of the stars in this volume using redshift and proper motion for movement and brightness and classification to estimate approximate mass and distance, so one might be able to hazard a guess. But all it takes is one fairly close encounter with an object of some uncertainty to make the guess invalid.